Can I make calculate bones constraints alternately?
Well, I have couple bones with constraints and when I move it, they act a little weird, so I need calculate constraints bones in especially order, for example: all constraints calculate in bone.01, then in bone.02, etc.
I have next relations: Gun which attracted to left hand with constraint "Copy Global Transform", and right hand which attracted to gun with "Inverse Kinematic", I guess when I move left hand then all constraints of bones calculates at the same time or in different order, and if there second case - I would like change this order, Can i do it?
Video with my the problem: https://youtu.be/DnRDTumPLbs 
Using Blender 3.6.9

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
